# Why am I getting this unary operator expected error?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I get a number from a string and convert it to an INT using the expr command in bash.  I then want to see if that first number is greater than the second number.  When I run the script, I am getting: `unary operator expected`

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

name1="19.5"
name2="19.1"
name3=`expr $name1`
name4=`expr $name2`

if [ $name3 >= $name4 ]; then
    echo "${name3} is greater than ${name4}"
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?  Am I not converting the string number to an INT correctly?

Comment: You aren't converting it to an int at all; did you look at the values of `name3` or `name4`? Also, `[` doesn't have a `>=` operator; if the values *were* integers, you would use `-ge`.

Comment: The problem is that, since `>=` isn't a recognized operator, it's interpreted as the redirection operator `>` followed by a file name `=` (you should have an empty file name `=` in your directory now). The command is parsed the same as `[ $name3 $name4] >=`, and `[`, with only 2 arguments (ignoring the final `]` argument) expects its first one to be a unary operator.

Comment: @jberthia : If you really want to turn your fractional numbers into integers (why?), do you want the floor, the ceil, or rounding the values?

Comment: BTW, you probably have an empty file named "=" (because of `>=` being recognized as an output redirection). You might want to delete it. BTW2, this is another case where `set -x` would help figure out what's going on. With it, you'd see that the shell is executing (among other things) `name3=19.5`, `name4=19.1`, and `'[' 19.5 19.1 ']'` (that's the command executed with output redirected to "=").

Answer (score 0):

`>` is the operator for redirecting standard output. Hence you are trying to redirect the stdout of the `]` command to a file named `=`, which leaves `[` with only two arguments ($name3 and $name4).

Hence, if you want to do **textual** comparision, then instead of `[`, you have to use `[[ ... ]]`, which is not a *command*, but part of bash *syntax*, and between the brackets, the redirection rules don't apply. However, you still don't have `<=` as an operator, but only `<` and `>`. In your case, this will be

```
if [[ ! $name4 < $name3 ]]; then ....
```

If you want to compare floating point numbers, and stick to bash, you can use `bc` and do

```
if [[ $(bc <<< "$name3 <=  $name4") == 1 ]]; then
```

or you write your complete shell script in zsh instead of bash, and get floating point arithmetic for free:

```
if (( name3 >= name4 )); then  # zsh only!
```

Comment: String comparison won't do what the OP wants, though. `10 < 2` is true.

Comment: I thought that the OP wants to compare two strings (consisting of digits and period(s)), such as version strings. But you are right: I overlooked the use of `expr`, which suggests that he wants to do decimal number comparision. I will update my answer.

Comment: The OP appeared to think that `expr` would convert a floating-point string to an integer.

Comment: Ah, I see. I will update my answer with a integer conversion solution, as soon the OP specifies precisely what he wants.